# Editable NSTextField autoresizing ... never works. Bug in OS X?

Tags: cocoa, nstextfield

I've got this problem on multiple projects with Xcode4/OS X 10.6:

[image]

No matter what I do, the editable NSTextField (containing text "Label") will *never* stick to the right-edge of the parent NSView.

The immediately adjacent NSTextfield (non-editable, text "Sprint Goal") *always* resizes correctly - with the exact same springs/struts it glues to the right-edge of the parent NSView.

I've got the same generic problem in multiple projects - right-hand-edges of editable NSTextField instances, with floating left-edge, are never, ever honoured. No matter what I do.

Bug? Something fundamental I'm missing here? All my other widgets and controls work "as expected", even with complex layouts. I can't get NSTextField to work even with simple layotus!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!

Possible bug in XCode4, plus human error.

When you single-click an NSTextField, it will sometimes consistently select the item BENEATH that textfield.

In each case in my current project, I had "something" behind the front field - usually a non-editable version of the same field that I was switching back/and forth to based on editable status.

(so I was selecting the NSTextField - but Xcode4 was selecting the item behind it - and then I was making changes to a different item altogether. So, the textfield was retaining its default settings - which are to stick to left, not right)